# Can one complete a morphism of commutative triangles to a "commutative cube" in a triangulated category?

Tags: reference-request, homological-algebra, kt.k-theory-and-homology, triangulated-categories

This question is a continuation of [Can one extend a morphism of commutative triangles to a morphism of  octahedral diagrams?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/24524/can-one-extend-a-morphism-of-commutative-triangles-to-a-morphism-of-octahedral).
I am deeply grateful for the contributions there; they roughly say that given a morphism of commutative triangles in a triangulated category one:

1) cannot extend it (in general) to a morphism of certain fixed octahedra "constructed from" these triangles.

2) is not able to prove the existence of such a morphism for some possible choice of octahedra of this sort (for general triangulated categories, without assuming certain additional axioms).

Now my question is: which "parts" of the morphism of octahedra diagram can be chosen to be commutative (in two settings: if the octahedra are fixed or not)? In particular, for $X\to Y\to Z$ and $X'\to Y'\to Z'$ I would like to consider the cubic diagram whose vertices are $X,Y,Cone(Y\to Z)[-1],Cone(X\to Z)[-1]$ + the corresponding vertices for the remaining triangle (i.e., $X',Y',Cone(Y'\to Z')[-1],Cone('X\to Z')[-1]$). Can one "make it commutative"?

Any hints and references would be very welcome!